# Using Foreach on iQueryable List find value if in 2nd List

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections, foreach

I have a iQueryable collection created with a query as seen below -

```
var Results = DataClass.Links.OrderBy(mySel => mySel.Description)
                             .Where(mySel =>                                     mySel.Report_Id.Equals(NumID)                                          
                             new Sections
                             {
                                SectID = mySel.Report_Section.SectID,
                                SectionDesn = mySel.Report_Section.ReportSectionDescription,
                                ReportPageTitle = mySel.tbl_Report.ReportPageTitle,                                                
                                MyUrl = mySel.Link_Url
                             }).Distinct();
```

I also have a second list of type `List<string>` called LookForMe defined as

```
var LookForMe = new List<string> { "increase", "abc", "tuesday", "another" };
```

I am now trying to loop through each item in my Results collection and if the item.URL contains one of the values found in my LookForMe list and if so then do something.

```
foreach (var item in Results)
{
   if (item.URL *contains any of the values in my LookFormE list*)
   {
      // then do something
   }
}
```

I'm not sure how to write the if statement to find if the current iterated value contains any of the values in the LookForMe list.  Any ideas to get me on the right track?   Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
foreach (var item in Results)
{
    if (LookForMe.Any(x=>item.URL.Contains(x)) 
    {
        // then do something
    }
}
```

Using the `Any` extension method, you are looking if there exists any of the worlds in `LookForMe`, which is included in the `item.URL`. If so, it returns true. Otherwise, it returns false.

Comment: Now it's the follow-up question that still leaves me hanging http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23834346/updating-local-iqueryable-list-before-returning-to-method-call

Answer (score 1):

Your check should be:

```
if(LookForMe.Contains(item.URL))
```

This will return true if `item.URL` is present in the List `LookForMe`.

**But if you are trying to compare any part** of `URL` matching any item in your List then your check should be:

```
if(LookForMe.Any(r=> item.URL.Contains(r)))
```

Comment: If you're going to use the collection Contains approach, and especially if there are many entries in the collection, it'd be better to call ToLookup , http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/03/24/c.net-little-wonders-the-tolookup-linq-extension-method.aspx , when defining LookForMe to generate an "indexed" lookup instead of basically the scan that happens when you call Contains. You then check the result of the lookup against null to check for existence.

Comment: Appreciate both comments.  Thank you.