# Updating local iqueryable list before returning to method call

Tags: c#, linq, collections, foreach

In a follow-up question to my original post [Using Foreach on iQueryable List find value if in 2nd List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833106/using-foreach-on-iqueryable-list-find-value-if-in-2nd-list/23833180?noredirect=1#23833180) I am unable to find a solution where when I make a change using the foreach loop it updates the local list.  Walking through my visual studio debugger it does update the item.LinkURL value if the current item is found in the LookForMe list. But when returning the Results.ToList() back to my calling method this update is not in the returned collection.  How do I save these into the Results list before returning them?   Not seeing any intellisense where something like Results.Update() or Results.Save() would work.

```
  foreach (var item in Results)
        {
            if (LookForME.Any(fs => item.LinkUrl.Contains(fs)))
            {
                item.LinkUrl = ServerPath + "/" + item.LinkUrl;   
                // works great until its time to return the updated Results list                 
            }
               // something here to update results with new value?
        }

        return Results.ToList();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to **iterate first** using `ToList` and the modify the in-memory list and return that.

Currently your `Result` is `IQueryable` *(more like a query)* which has yet to be executed.

You can do that like:

```
var newList = Result.ToList(); //get a in-memory list
foreach (var item in newList) //modify in-memory list
{
        if (LookForME.Any(fs => item.LinkUrl.Contains(fs)))
        {
            item.LinkUrl = ServerPath + "/" + item.LinkUrl;   
            // works great until its time to return the updated Results list                 
        }
           // something here to update results with new value?
}

return newList;
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  Deferred Execution get me again?> :-)  Thanks so much.